# Using regex for either number and alphabetic with length

Tags: java, regex

To validate value With Length More than 7 And Contains `Alphabetic` And `Number` C-Characters i user the below Regex :

```
"^([A-Za-z][0-9])(\\w{7,})*"
```

Language is JAVA and `\` most be `\\` In this Language

Comment: So, what is your issue?

Comment: If I understand well, you want to validate a string that is of 7 characters length minimum and that can contain letters & numbers, is that correct?

Comment: Should it contain at least one alphabet and one digit? Or can it be all digits or all alphabets?

Comment: @Niitaku Yes! exactly need it

Comment: @NaveedS  alphabet  And digit Both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you need to allow all digit or all alphabet inputs as well**

You just need `^[A-Za-z0-9]{7,}$` which would accept any character from A to Z or a to z or 0 to 9 (denoted by the character class) occurring 7 or more times.

**If you need to allow only if at least one digit and one alphabet is there**

Use `^(?=.*[A-Za-z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)[A-Za-z0-9]{7,}$`, which has look-aheads for alphabet `(?=.*[A-Za-z].*)` and digit `(?=.*[0-9].*)` to confirm that at least a digit and an alphabet is there, followed by a character class to restrict the characters to alphabets and letters set with a minimum length of 7.

Comment: it works only when string start with alphabets for ex. "ABCD1234" is OK But "1234ABCD" Not Accepted

Comment: @AndroSco `"1234ABCD".matches(regex)` gives **true** for me. (`regex` is the String holding the pattern)

Comment: @AndroSco can you add the code snippet to the question? The regex works when I checked as above.

Comment: my coworker used and told me 'can not handle it' , may be 'user Error'